# The cooling will go out

Tags: word-usage

I had turned on the AC and the room had cooled down after a while.  Later on my brother opened up the door,  so I wanted him to close the door.  I know I can simply say "Close the door",  but I want to emphasize on the consequence of opening the door.

> The cooling will go out.

By 'go out" I mean "go out of the room"

> The room will become hot.
>
> The room will get hot.

And  after it has happened:

> The room has gotten hot.

Answer (score 1):

> Close the door! You're letting the cold (air) out!

Comment: I think your answer is most idiomatic, but could you elaborate?  You haven't provide enough detail why this is correct for me to want to upvote.

Comment: It's what I'd say, as a native British English speaker.

Comment: Well, yeah, as an American, it's what I'd say too.  What I mean is that a good answer should provide more.  Here's a discussion with some pointers:  https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4840/when-should-i-upvote

Comment: Will "air" be dropped?

Comment: And what about the other three sentences? (The ones with "hot"?)

Answer (score 0):

The *cold air* will *get* out is more idiomatic.

*Cooling* usually describes an action; using it here to mean cold air is not standard.

*Will get out* carries the implication that we do not want it to get out - we want it contained.